# Stack level too deep in method_missing

Tags: ruby

I have the following Ruby method which is giving the RSpec error 'stack level too deep' and I'm not sure why - any help is much appreciated!

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args)
  full_method_name = "#{self.class.to_s.downcase}_#{method_name.to_s}"
  respond_to(:full_method_name) ? send(:full_method_name, @options) : super
end
```

Comment: I guess, there's no such method `respond_to`. Also, your variable `full_method_name` is not used

Comment: `options` is not defined and method_missing is called for it as well, and again and again.

Comment: @avlazarov it seems like a challenge, who finds more errors in this short snippet :)

Comment: you're sending the symbol `:full_method_name` not the value like `send(full_method_name, @options)`

Comment: Thanks all, working now.

Comment: `method_missing` is often a bear to debug, "stack level too deep" being a common refrain. One thing you can do is create an instance variable `@mm_level = 0` outside the method and at the beginning of the method, increment the counter, add `puts "method = #{method_name}, args = #{args}"` and `exit` when the counter gets to a particular value.

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter a `stack level too deep` error, it usually means you didn't properly write your invariant for a recursive method and ruby is stuck recursively calling said method ad infinitum, filling up memory allocated for the stack.

TL;DR; **It's an infinite loop.**

That's exactly what's happening to you, except you aren't recursively calling `method_missing` explicitly, you're calling it *implicitly*. **You probably have a call to a method in `method_missing` that doesn't exist**. Check that method's existence.

**Specifically, the method `respond_to` doesn't exist, I think you mean `respond_to?`.**